# How to emulate word boundary when using unicode character properties?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8, locale

From my previous questions [Why under locale-pragma word characters do not match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863899/why-under-locale-pragma-word-characters-do-not-match) and [How to change nested quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921070/how-to-change-nested-quotes) I learnt that when dealing with UTF-8 data you can't trust `\w` as word-char and you must use the Unicode character property `\p{Word}`. Now I am in a situation where I found that zero-width word boundary `\b` also does not work with UTF-8 (with locale enabled), but I did not find any equivalent in Unicode character properties. I thought I may construct it myself like: `(?<=\P{Word})(\p{Word}+)(?=\P{Word})`, it should be equivalent to `\b(\w+)\b`.

In the test script below I have two arrays to test two different regexes. The first based on `\b` works fine when locale is not enabled. To get it to also work with locales I wrote another version with emulating boundary `(?=\P{Word})` but it does not work as I expected (I show expected results in script too).

Do you see what is wrong and how to get emulated regex work as first with ASCII (or without locale)?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use utf8::all;
use locale; # et_EE.UTF-8 in my case
$| = 1;

my @test_boundary = (  # EXPECTED RESULT:
  '"abc def"',         # '«abc def»'
  '"abc "d e f" ghi"', # '«abc «d e f» ghi»'
  '"abc "d e f""',     # '«abc «d e f»»'
  '"abc "d e f"',      # '«abc "d e f»'
  '"abc "d" "e" f"',   # '«abc «d» «e» f»'
  # below won't work with \b when locale enabled
  '"100 Естонiï"',     #  '«100 Естонiï»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü" ï"',   # '«äöõ «ä õ ü» ï»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü""',     # '«äöõ «ä õ ü»»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü"',      # '«äöõ «ä õ ü»'
  '"äöõ "ä" "õ" ï"',   # '«äöõ «ä» «õ» ï»'
);

my @test_emulate = (   # EXPECTED RESULT:
  '"100 Естонiï"',     # '«100 Естонiï»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü" ï"',   # '«äöõ «ä õ ü» ï»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü""',     # '«äöõ «ä õ ü»»'
  '"äöõ "ä õ ü"',      # '«äöõ "ä õ ü»'
  '"äöõ "ä" "õ" ï"',   # '«äöõ «ä» «õ» ï»'
);

say "BOUNDARY";
for my $sentence ( @test_boundary ) {
  my $quote_count = ( $sentence =~ tr/"/"/ );

  for ( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $quote_count ; $i += 2 ) {
    $sentence =~ s/
      "(                          # first qoute, start capture
        [\p{Word}\.]+?            # suva word-char
        .*?\b[\.,?!»]*?           # any char followed boundary + opt. punctuation
      )"                          # stop capture, ending quote
      /«$1»/xg;                   # change to fancy
  }
  say $sentence;
}

say "EMULATE";
for my $sentence ( @test_emulate ) {
  my $quote_count =  ( $sentence =~ tr/"/"/ );

  for ( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $quote_count ; $i += 2 ) {
    $sentence =~ s/
      "(                         # first qoute, start capture
      [\p{Word}\.]+?             # at least one word-char or point
      .*?(?=\P{Word})            # any char followed boundary 
      [\.,?!»]*?                 # optional punctuation
      )"                         # stop capture, ending quote
      /«$1»/gx;                  # change to fancy
  }
  say $sentence;
}
```

Comment: First, you are mistaken: `\w` and `\p{word}` are by definition identical.  But second, ***please, please, please*** do not use the `use locale` pragma. It is broken, unreliable, unpredictable, and a royal pain in the butt — as you seem to have discovered.  You should be  using the  `Unicode::Collate::Locale` module.  You should probably not be using `use utf8:all` either, but rather doing the specific things that you want.

Comment: @tchrist:  `\w` and `\p{Word}` may be defined identical, but they behave differently under `use locale`. Of course, i will not use locale when i have other way now. `use utf8::all` satisfies my needs pretty well and it is clean way to show my intentions. If there is some lack in utf8::all, maybe you could point it to the author?

Comment: You don’t know what `utf8:all` does or does not do, which is precisely the problem — a problem, I note, that cannot be fixed by adding things to it.  What level of `utf8` warnings do you get? None or warning or fatal? What about the three subtypes, the nonchar and the surrogates and the non_unicode? These things should be explicit in the code so people can see what they are.  Then there is the issue of rendering into NFD on input and NFC on output; does it do that?

Comment: @tchrist: I understand `utf8::all` internals much better than `DBI`, `Unicode::Collate::Locale` or Perl core internals, but that does not stop me use them in my limited scope so well as I can. I have never worried about normalization, for example. When i will one day, i'll dig deeper. It is normal abstraction level for me - not to worry about underlying details when they don't make sense enough but work like expected. For time when `utf8::all` came up I already put most of the picture together myself too. But with using it I say: there is some "wheel" you all could use. I miss it being in core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the character after the position of the `\b` is either some punctuation or `"` (to be safe, please double check that `\p{Word}` does not match any of them), it falls into the case `\b\W`. Therefore, we can emulate `\b` with:

```
(?<=\p{Word})
```

I am not familiar with Perl, but from [what I tested here](http://ideone.com/6YgBTX), it seems that `\w` (and `\b`) also works nicely when the encoding is set to UTF-8.

```
$sentence =~ s/
  "(
    [\w\.]+?
    .*?\b[\.,?!»]*?
  )"
  /«$1»/xg;
```

If you move up to Perl 5.14 and above, you can set the character set to Unicode with `u` flag.

---

You can use this general strategy to construct a boundary corresponding to a character class. (Like how `\b` word boundary definition is based on the definition of `\w`).

Let `C` be the character class. We would like to define a boundary that is based on the character class C.

The construction below will emulate boundary in front when you know the current character belongs to `C` character class (equivalent to `(\b\w)`):

```
(?<!C)C
```

Or behind (equivalent to `\w\b`):

```
C(?!C)
```

*Why negative look-around?* Because positive look-around (with the complementary character class) will also assert that there must be a character ahead/behind (assert *width* ahead/behind at least 1). Negative look-around will allow for the case of beginning/ending of the string without writing a cumbersome regex.

---

For `\B\w` emulation:

```
(?<=C)C
```

and similarly `\w\B`:

```
C(?=C)
```

`\B` is the direct opposite of `\b`, therefore, we can just flip the positive/negative look-around to emulate the effect. It also makes sense - a non-boundary can only be formed when there are more character ahead/behind.

---

Other emulations (let `c` be the complement character class of `C`):

- `\b\W`: `(?<=C)c`
- `\W\b`: `c(?=C)`
- `\B\W`: `(?<!C)c`
- `\W\B`: `c(?!C)`

---

For the emulation of a standalone boundary (equivalent to `\b`):

```
(?:(?<!C)(?=C)|(?<=C)(?!C))
```

And standalone non-boundary (equivalent to `\B`):

```
(?:(?<!C)(?!C)|(?<=C)(?=C))
```

Comment: Changing `\b` into `(?!\p{Word})` did not change the results. With testcase `'"äöõ "ä õ ü" ï"'` i get captured instead of `äöõ "ä õ ü` still `äöõ `, like with my positive lookaround. Could you point, what goes wrong?

Comment: @w.k: I am not sure what you are trying to do (bracket matching?). The problem is not about word boundary (and its emulation), but with the regex that you are currently having.

Comment: My goal is to change pairs of double quotes`"äöõ"` into fancy quotes `«äöõ»`. On nested quotes it should replace not matching pairs but 1st and 3rd quote, then 2nd and 4th. My first regex works exactly as i expected when i don't enable locale. But i need locale too. So, in second regex only change i made is changing `\b` into `(?=\P{Word})` and after your suggestion into negative lookahead `(?!\p{Word})`. Those lookaheads don't work as `\b` did and i don't see why?

Comment: @w.k: I am not sure how you identify 2 quotes as a pair and change them into fancy quote. I am not sure you know what you are doing in your original regex: http://pastebin.com/DVUqzSYb

Comment: Hmm, but the match on the line 46 is exactly what i am looking for. I want to get same match with emulated boundary too, but i can't so far. `$1` becomes string which i want to surround with fancy quotes. Where do you see problem? In too many repeats?

Comment: @w.k: Oh, I see your problem when I run your code on ideone (but there is limit to what I can do on ideone). Can you try `(?<=\p{Word})`? Since your case is equivalent to `\b\W`.

Comment: Yes, it works. So, you checked that the previous char should be word char with this lookbehind. Could you please edit your answer to incorporate this information into it?

Comment: Thank you, accepted it. Problem with `\w` (and `b` ) rises only with `use locale` (which i need for sorting by my locale standards). When not enforcing locale they work fine, because then `\w` is equal to `\p{Word}` (if Unicode rules are in effect). More details on [perlrecharclass documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Word-characters)

Comment: @w.k ***Please, please, please*** do not use the `use locale` pragma.    Use `Unicode::Collate::Locale`.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\p{Word})(\p{Word}+)(?!\p{Word})
```

The positive lookarounds fail at the start or end of the string because they require a non-word character to be present. The negative lookarounds work in both cases.

Comment: Isn’t that just like writing `\b(\w+)\b`?

Comment: He’s messing things up with the icky/broken `use locale`; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15036072/471272) for how to do locale stuff in Perl the right way. That way you can just use normal regex things, too.